# std::map difference between index and insert calls

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, hashmap

What is the difference between the index overloaded operator and the insert method call for std::map?

ie:

```
some_map["x"] = 500;
```

vs.

```
some_map.insert(pair<std::string, int>("x", 500));
```

Comment: The first one is much more readable ;)

Comment: Using make_pair() would help on the insert because it can deduce the argument types: "some_map.insert(std::make_pair("x", 500));"

Comment: @Fred Larson: Although the `make_pair` you show would deduce `const char*` and `int` so an implicit conversion from one `pair` type to the actual `value_type` of the `map` will be generated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In STL maps, is it better to use map::insert than \[\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe insert() will not overwrite an existing value, and the result of the operation can be checked by testing the bool value in the iterator/pair value returned

The assignment to the subscript operator [] just overwrites whatever's there (inserting an entry if there isn't one there already)

Either of the insert and [] operators can cause issues if you're not expecting that behaviour and don't accommodate for it.

Eg with insert:

```
std::map< int, std::string* > intMap;
std::string* s1 = new std::string;
std::string* s2 = new std::string;
intMap.insert( std::make_pair( 100, s1 ) ); // inserted
intMap.insert( std::make_pair( 100, s2 ) ); // fails, s2 not in map, could leak if not tidied up
```

and with [] operator:

```
std::map< int, std::string* > intMap;
std::string* s1 = new std::string;
std::string* s2 = new std::string;
intMap[ 100 ] = s1; // inserted
intMap[ 100 ] = s2; // inserted, s1 now dropped from map, could leak if not tidied up
```

I think those are correct, but haven't compiled them, so may have syntax errors

Comment: You were right, map[i] is good for overwrite, but map.insert() does not overwrite sometimes, I recently faced this behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

For a `map`, the former (`operator[]`) expression will always replace the value part of the key-value pair with the new supplied value. A new key-value pair will be inserted if one doesn't already exist.

In contrast, `insert` will only insert a new key-value pair if a key-value pair with the supplied key part does not already exist in the map.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the fact that `map::operator[]` will replace an existing value is that `operator[]` map::will **create and add to the map** a default existing value to replace before the replacement occurs (the `map::operator[]()` call has to return a reference to something).  For items that are expensive to create this could be a performance issue.

See "Item 24: Choose carefully between `map::operator[]` and `map::insert` when efficiency is important" in [Scott Meyers' Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876).

Answer (score 0):

The insert method inserts into the map, while the overloaded index operator will return the element with the key key_value if it is in the map, if it is not already in the map then it will insert it.

Comment: It'll only insert into the map if a given key is not already present. If it is present, insert() will not update the value whereas an assignment to operator[] will.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Michael Burr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594631/stdmap-difference-between-index-and-insert-calls/1595488#1595488), the book you should be looking for is Scott Meyer's <[Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004V4432W)> not the <Effective C++>, as Michael has linked it wrongly.

> the expression
>
> `m[k] = v;`
>
> checks to see if the key k is already in the map. If not, it’s
> added, along with v as its corresponding value. If k is already in the
> map, its associated value is updated to v.

(when adding new k-v)

> We first default-construct a <value obj>, then we immediately assign
> it a new value. If it’s **measurably more efficient to construct a
> <value obj>** with the value we want **instead of default-constructing** the
> <value obj> and then doing the assignment, we’d be **better off** replacing our
> use of operator[] (including its attendant construction plus
> assignment) **with a straightforward call to insert**:

(updating existing k's v)

> we now understand that when an “add” is performed, insert is more
> efficient than operator[]. **The situation is reversed when we do an
> update**, i.e., when an equivalent key is already in the
> map.