# difference between two ways to insert into map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I was asked the two ways to insert a record to a map,

```
mymap["foo"] = 123;

mymap.insert("foo", 123);
```

so is there any difference between these two except the syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::map difference between index and insert calls.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594631/stdmap-difference-between-index-and-insert-calls)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to Timo's excellent answer--

If no element at "foo" exists, the first will first default construct a value at the "foo" location, THEN using a reference to the default constructed "foo" value, assign 123 to that location.

Just doing

```
mymap["foo"]
```

will cause a value to be default constructed and placed at the "foo" location. So be careful when doing

```
int value = mymap["foo"]
```

because it will work, *even if you never explicitly assigned or inserted at foo*

Comment: Fairly obvious implications of the above: 1) using the indexing `operator[]` requires `value_type` support for default construction, whereas you can `insert()` regardless. 2) default construction wastes a little time.

Answer (score 9):

There is, the first option via `[]` will overwrite the value stored with the key "foo" if a key "foo" exists, whereas `insert` will fail to insert data if the key already exists and will indicate success or failure in its return value.