# What is the preferred/idiomatic way to insert into a map?

Tags: c++, stl, insert, stdmap, std-pair

I have identified four different ways of inserting elements into a `std::map`:

```
std::map<int, int> function;

function[0] = 42;
function.insert(std::map<int, int>::value_type(0, 42));
function.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 42));
function.insert(std::make_pair(0, 42));
```

Which of those is the preferred/idiomatic way? (And is there another way I have not thought of?)

Comment: Your map should be called "answers", not "function"

Comment: @Vincent: Hm? A function is basically a map between two sets.

Comment: @FredOverflow: seems Vincent's comment is kinda joke about certain book...

Comment: It seems to contradict the original -- 42 can't simultaneously be the answer to (a) life, the universe and everything, and (b) nothing. But then how do you express life, the universe and everything as an int?

Comment: @sgolodetz You can express everything with an int large enough.

Comment: @ybungalobill Ah! Godel wouldn't be happy of your comment! Probably you must read (or re-read) the wonderful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach

Comment: The way I currently see, if `42` can throw, for the first version it's not defined whether the map will contain a {0, default_constructed} or not.

Comment: @ybungalobill or pi...

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Can you express something in terms of a number where that number must be larger than infinity or even larger than infinity to the infinity power...? How about something that is eternal such as Spirit?

Comment: Since the *Integers* are _countable_ (aleph-null), use *Reals*, or better yet, a 4-tuple of *Complex*

Answer (score 113, accepted):

First of all, `operator[]` and `insert` member functions are not functionally equivalent :

- The `operator[]` will *search* for the key, insert a *default constructed* value if not found, and return a reference to which you assign a value. Obviously, this can be inefficient if the `mapped_type` can benefit from being directly initialized instead of default constructed and assigned. This method also makes it impossible to determine if an insertion has indeed taken place or if you have only overwritten the value for an previously inserted key
- The `insert` member function will have no effect if the key is already present in the map and, although it is often forgotten, returns an `std::pair<iterator, bool>` which can be of interest (most notably to determine if insertion has actually been done).

From all the listed possibilities to call `insert`, all three are *almost* equivalent. As a reminder, let's have look at `insert` signature in the standard :

```
typedef pair<const Key, T> value_type;

  /* ... */

pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& x);
```

So how are the three calls different ?

- `std::make_pair` relies on template argument deduction and could (and in this case *will*) produce something of a different type than the actual `value_type` of the map, which will require an additional call to `std::pair` template constructor in order to convert to `value_type` (ie : adding `const` to `first_type`)
- `std::pair<int, int>` will also require an additional call to the template constructor of `std::pair` in order to convert the parameter to `value_type` (ie : adding `const` to `first_type`)
- `std::map<int, int>::value_type` leaves absolutely no place for doubt as it is directly the parameter type expected by the `insert` member function.

In the end, I would avoid using `operator[]` when the objective is to insert, unless there is no additional cost in default-constructing and assigning the `mapped_type`, and that I don't care about determining if a new key has effectively inserted. When using `insert`, constructing a `value_type` is probably the way to go.

Comment: does the conversion from Key to const Key in make_pair() really request another function call? It seems an implicit cast would suffice which compiler should be happy to do so.

Answer (score 151):

As of C++11, you have two major additional options. First, you can use `insert()` with list initialization syntax:

```
function.insert({0, 42});
```

This is functionally equivalent to

```
function.insert(std::map<int, int>::value_type(0, 42));
```

but much more concise and readable. As other answers have noted, this has several advantages over the other forms:

- The `operator[]` approach requires the mapped type to be assignable, which isn't always the case.
- The `operator[]` approach can overwrite existing elements, and gives you no way to tell whether this has happened.
- The other forms of `insert` that you list involve an implicit type conversion, which may slow your code down.

The major drawback is that this form used to require the key and value to be copyable, so it wouldn't work with e.g. a map with `unique_ptr` values. That has been fixed in the standard, but the fix may not have reached your standard library implementation yet.

Second, you can use the `emplace()` method:

```
function.emplace(0, 42);
```

This is more concise than any of the forms of `insert()`, works fine with move-only types like `unique_ptr`, and theoretically may be slightly more efficient (although a decent compiler should optimize away the difference). The only major drawback is that it may surprise your readers a little, since `emplace` methods aren't usually used that way.

Comment: there is also the new [insert_or_assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) and [try_emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)

Comment: Isn't `function.insert({0, 42});` a Most Vexing Parse case?

Comment: No; the Most Vexing Parse is when something you intend to be a variable declaration gets parsed as a function declaration. This can't be parsed as a function declaration, and it's not intended to be a variable declaration anyway, so the MVP isn't an issue.

Answer (score 17):

Since [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) offers two new insertion methods: [`insert_or_assign()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) and [`try_emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace), as also mentioned in the [comment by sp2danny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/preferred-idiomatic-way-to-insert-into-a-map#comment57789942_19942780).

### `insert_or_assign()`

Basically, `insert_or_assign()` is an "improved" version of [`operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at). In contrast to `operator[]`, `insert_or_assign()` doesn't require the map's value type to be default constructible. For example, the following code doesn't compile, because `MyClass` does not have a default constructor:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int i) : m_i(i) {};
    int m_i;
};

int main() {
    std::map<int, MyClass> myMap;

    // VS2017: "C2512: 'MyClass::MyClass' : no appropriate default constructor available"
    // Coliru: "error: no matching function for call to 'MyClass::MyClass()"
    myMap[0] = MyClass(1);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you replace `myMap[0] = MyClass(1);` by the following line, then the code compiles and the insertion takes place as intended:

```
myMap.insert_or_assign(0, MyClass(1));
```

Moreover, similar to [`insert()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert), `insert_or_assign()` returns a `pair<iterator, bool>`. The Boolean value is `true` if an insertion occurred and `false` if an assignment was done. The iterator points to the element that was inserted or updated.

### `try_emplace()`

Similar to the above, `try_emplace()` is an "improvement" of [`emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). In contrast to `emplace()`, `try_emplace()` doesn't modify its arguments if insertion fails due to a key already existing in the map. For example, the following code attempts to emplace an element with a key that is already stored in the map (see *):

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> myMap2;
    myMap2.emplace(0, std::make_unique<MyClass>(1));

    auto pMyObj = std::make_unique<MyClass>(2);    
    auto [it, b] = myMap2.emplace(0, std::move(pMyObj));  // *

    if (!b)
        std::cout << "pMyObj was not inserted" << std::endl;

    if (pMyObj == nullptr)
        std::cout << "pMyObj was modified anyway" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "pMyObj.m_i = " << pMyObj->m_i <<  std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output (at least for VS2017 and Coliru):

> pMyObj was not inserted
>   pMyObj was modified anyway

As you can see, `pMyObj` no longer points to the original object. However, if you replace `auto [it, b] = myMap2.emplace(0, std::move(pMyObj));` by the the following code, then the output looks different, because `pMyObj` remains unchanged:

```
auto [it, b] = myMap2.try_emplace(0, std::move(pMyObj));
```

Output:

> pMyObj was not inserted
>   pMyObj pMyObj.m_i = 2

[Code on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6fe61c69a56b144)

Please note: I tried to keep my explanations as short and simple as possible to fit them into this answer. For a more precise and comprehensive description, I recommend reading [this article](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/12/11/overview-of-std-map-insertion-emplacement-methods-in-cpp17/) on *Fluent C++*.

Answer (score 13):

The first version:

```
function[0] = 42; // version 1
```

may or may not insert the value 42 into the map. If the key `0` exists, then it will assign 42 to that key, overwriting whatever value that key had. Otherwise it inserts the key/value pair.

The insert functions:

```
function.insert(std::map<int, int>::value_type(0, 42));  // version 2
function.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 42));             // version 3
function.insert(std::make_pair(0, 42));                  // version 4
```

on the other hand, don't do anything if the key `0` already exists in the map. If the key doesn't exist, it inserts the key/value pair.

The three insert functions are almost identical. `std::map<int, int>::value_type` is the `typedef` for `std::pair<const int, int>`, and `std::make_pair()` obviously produces a `std::pair<>` via template deduction magic. The end result, however, should be the same for versions 2, 3, and 4.

Which one would I use? I personally prefer version 1; it's concise and "natural". Of course, if its overwriting behavior is not desired, then I would prefer version 4, since it requires less typing than versions 2 and 3. I don't know if there is a single *de facto* way of inserting key/value pairs into a `std::map`.

Another way to insert values into a map via one of its constructors:

```
std::map<int, int> quadratic_func;

quadratic_func[0] = 0;
quadratic_func[1] = 1;
quadratic_func[2] = 4;
quadratic_func[3] = 9;

std::map<int, int> my_func(quadratic_func.begin(), quadratic_func.end());
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to overwrite the element with key 0

```
function[0] = 42;
```

Otherwise:

```
function.insert(std::make_pair(0, 42));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been running some time comparisons between the abovementioned versions:

```
function[0] = 42;
function.insert(std::map<int, int>::value_type(0, 42));
function.insert(std::pair<int, int>(0, 42));
function.insert(std::make_pair(0, 42));
```

Turns out that time differences between the insert versions are tiny.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using namespace boost::posix_time;
class Widget {
public:
    Widget() {
        m_vec.resize(100);
        for(unsigned long it = 0; it < 100;it++) {
            m_vec[it] = 1.0;
        }
    }
    Widget(double el)   {
        m_vec.resize(100);
        for(unsigned long it = 0; it < 100;it++) {
            m_vec[it] = el;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<double> m_vec;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {



    std::map<int,Widget> map_W;
    ptime t1 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();    
    for(int it = 0; it < 10000;it++) {
        map_W.insert(std::pair<int,Widget>(it,Widget(2.0)));
    }
    ptime t2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    time_duration diff = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << diff.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

    std::map<int,Widget> map_W_2;
    ptime t1_2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();    
    for(int it = 0; it < 10000;it++) {
        map_W_2.insert(std::make_pair(it,Widget(2.0)));
    }
    ptime t2_2 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    time_duration diff_2 = t2_2 - t1_2;
    std::cout << diff_2.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

    std::map<int,Widget> map_W_3;
    ptime t1_3 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();    
    for(int it = 0; it < 10000;it++) {
        map_W_3[it] = Widget(2.0);
    }
    ptime t2_3 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    time_duration diff_3 = t2_3 - t1_3;
    std::cout << diff_3.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

    std::map<int,Widget> map_W_0;
    ptime t1_0 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();    
    for(int it = 0; it < 10000;it++) {
        map_W_0.insert(std::map<int,Widget>::value_type(it,Widget(2.0)));
    }
    ptime t2_0 = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    time_duration diff_0 = t2_0 - t1_0;
    std::cout << diff_0.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

This gives respectively for the versions (I ran the file 3 times, hence the 3 consecutive time differences for each):

```
map_W.insert(std::pair<int,Widget>(it,Widget(2.0)));
```

2198 ms, 2078 ms, 2072 ms

```
map_W_2.insert(std::make_pair(it,Widget(2.0)));
```

2290 ms, 2037 ms, 2046 ms

```
 map_W_3[it] = Widget(2.0);
```

2592 ms, 2278 ms, 2296 ms

```
 map_W_0.insert(std::map<int,Widget>::value_type(it,Widget(2.0)));
```

2234 ms, 2031 ms, 2027 ms

Hence, results between different insert versions can be neglected (didn't perform a hypothesis test though)!

The `map_W_3[it] = Widget(2.0);` version takes about 10-15 % more time for this example due to an initialization with the default constructor for Widget.

Answer (score 3):

In short, `[]` operator is more efficient for updating values because it involves calling default constructor of the value type and then assigning it a new value, while `insert()` is more efficient for adding values.

The quoted snippet from *Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library* by Scott Meyers, Item 24 might help.

```
template<typename MapType, typename KeyArgType, typename ValueArgType>
typename MapType::iterator
insertKeyAndValue(MapType& m, const KeyArgType&k, const ValueArgType& v)
{
    typename MapType::iterator lb = m.lower_bound(k);

    if (lb != m.end() && !(m.key_comp()(k, lb->first))) {
        lb->second = v;
        return lb;
    } else {
        typedef typename MapType::value_type MVT;
        return m.insert(lb, MVT(k, v));
    }
}
```

You may decide to choose a generic-programming-free version of this, but the point is that I find this paradigm (differentiating 'add' and 'update') extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert element in std::map - use insert() function, and if you want to find element (by key) and assign some to it - use operator[].

For simplify inserting use boost::assign library, like this:

```
using namespace boost::assign;

// For inserting one element:

insert( function )( 0, 41 );

// For inserting several elements:

insert( function )( 0, 41 )( 0, 42 )( 0, 43 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I just change the problem a little bit (map of strings) to show another interest of insert:

```
std::map<int, std::string> rancking;

rancking[0] = 42;  // << some compilers [gcc] show no error

rancking.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(0, 42));// always a compile error
```

the fact that compiler shows no error on "rancking[1] = 42;" can have devastating impact !

Comment: Compilers don't show an error for the former because `std::string::operator=(char)` exists, but they show an error for the latter because the constructor `std::string::string(char)` does not exist. It *shouldn't* produce an error because C++ always freely interprets any integer-style literal as `char`, so this isn't a compiler bug, but instead is a programmer error. Basically, I'm just saying that whether or not that introduces a bug in your code is something you have to watch out for yourself. BTW, you can print `rancking[0]` and a compiler using ASCII will output `*`, which is `(char)(42)`.

Comment: See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/