# Insert elements into c++ map - differences of insert methods

Tags: c++, dictionary

What's the difference between those two versions of insertion into a c++ `map` :

```
map<string,double> myMap;
// version 1
myMap["david"] = 123.123;

// version 2
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("david" ,123.123));
```

Regards

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/how-do-i-insert-into-a-map) might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one will update the value if the key already exists, but the second one will **not** update it if the key already exists.

```
std::map<string,double> myMap;

//working with operator[]
myMap["david"] = 123.0; //inserts
myMap["david"] = 98.0;   //updates

std::cout << myMap["david"] << std::endl; //prints 98.0 (updated value)

//working with insert
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("nawaz", 100.0)); //inserts
myMap.insert(std::make_pair("nawaz", 878.0)); //no update

std::cout << myMap["nawaz"] << std::endl; //prints 100.0 (old value)
```

The `insert` function returns `std::pair<iterator,bool>`. The boolean value of the pair tells you whether the insertion was successful or not.

Now read the documentation for more detail:

- [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert)
- [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

Comment: In addition, if the value at `myMap["david"]` does not exist, it is default-constructed and then overwritten (which is why you can't use `operator[]` with maps that are `const`). This is less optimal than `insert`. Likewise, `insert` is probably less optimal in this case than `emplace`.