# C++: Inserting a Vector in a Map

Tags: c++, c++11

So I've created

```
 map<string, vector<int>> mylist;
```

but I'm having trouble adding items to it. I tried creating a vector and then inserting a string and the vector in the map, but visual studio is giving me an error on the line with the insert function 
(It says no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list). This is what I'm doing:

```
vector<int> variable_list(some_integer);
mylist.insert(string_variable, variable_list);
```

How should I be adding the vector to the map? Can I create the vector in the insert function somehow?

Also, I'll be initializing the vector with one int, but then I'll want to go back and add more later. How do I access a vector within a map?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you copy paste the precise error message please ?

Comment: See this question on how to insert to a map: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/how-do-i-insert-into-a-map

Comment: You can just do `my_map[key].push_back(value)`. If the `key` doesn't exist, it's created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map::insert` takes a `std::pair`.  You can either use `make_pair` or write `mylist[string_variable] = variable_list;`

Answer (score 4):

For this kind of question, I would recommend looking up a good reference, such as [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com).

If you go there and you look up `std::map::insert`, you will see overload with this signature: `std::pair<iterator,bool> insert( const value_type& value );`, which tells us that it expects something called `value_type`. If you then look at `std::map`, you will see that `value_type` is typedef for `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

Now you can use `std::make_pair` to create the proper type, like this: `mylist.insert(std::make_pair<const string, vector<int>)`.

As a side note, I have to strongly recommend finding an introductionary book/something, because the rest of your question suggests that you are rather confused about more than just inserting into map. 
For starters, `vector<int> variable_list(number)` will not construct a vector with `number` in it, but will construct a vector of `number` zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `mylist.insert(std::make_pair(string_variable, variable_list));`. You are looking for the version of [std::map::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) that takes the value_type as its argument, which, in your case, is `std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int>>`.