# map insert with pair type

Tags: c++, stl

While inserting an element in a map of type `<int,int>` , we have to explicitly mention the types again as pair. Isnt is redundant?

```
map<int,int> m1;
//m1.insert(1,1); //NOT OK since the pair type <int,int> not mentioned
m1.insert(pair<int,int>(1,1)); //OK
```

m1 is declared as `<int,int>`. Would there be any instance wherein we try to insert any element other than `<int,int>`  `e.g. m1.insert(pair<int,string>(1,"boo"))` ? If no, then isn't it redundant to write `<int,int>` again while inserting an element?

**EDIT 1:**

To explain in detail here is a small example:

```
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class Test
{
public:
    template<typename T1>
    void fun1()
    {
        cout<<"This is called for T1 templatized fun1"<<endl;
    }
    template <typename T1,typename T2>
    void insert(pair<T1,T2> &obj)
    {
        cout<<obj.first<<" "<<obj.second<<endl;     
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test <int,int>obj; // Even though i have declared obj as type int,int, i am still able to call insert on type int,string
    obj.insert(pair<int,string>(1,"Anurag"));
```

Here we clearly see that the types with which i created object *obj* is different than the types with which i called *insert()* .
But i dont understand how would the member function map::insert() make sure that the types are same as those with which the object is created?
One way that i thought of was:

```
template <typename T3=T1,typename T4=T2> //where T1 and T2 are class typenames
void insert2(pair<T3,T4>& obj2)
{
    cout<<"Inside insert2 \n";
}
```

But even this would not be allowed since this is a function template not a class template. I tried looking inside the header file of **map** to see the declaration of insert but got more confused.

Comment: Well, you can insert std::pair<char, char> or any other which can be implicitly casted to std::pair<int, int>.

Comment: Ivan but both compiles successfully here,
mymap.insert ( std::pair<char,char>('a','b') );

 mymap.insert ( std::pair<int,int>('k','l') );
Even mentioning in pair exclusively does not guarantee a strict type check .

Answer (score 4):

`insert` is not a forwarding function. Just use brackets to initialize the pair object:

```
m1.insert({1, 1});
```

In C++11, `emplace` will forward the arguments.

```
m1.emplace(1, 1);
```

Or in C++03, `make_pair`.

---

Regarding your edit:

That's a pretty inaccurate representation of map. A more accurate representation would be something like this:

```
template <typename Key, typename T,
          class Compare = std::less<Key>,
          class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>>
struct Test
{
    using value_type = std::pair<const Key, T>;
    using iterator   = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer;

    std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( const value_type& value )
    {
        // this calls emplace
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int, int> test;
    test.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(1, "hello"));
}
```

Which *does* give a compiler error. Of course, this is why the convenience function `std::make_pair` was provided in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's redundant, but that't the way it is. However, you can insert elements without having to respecify `<int,int>`.

This way, compiler is smart enough to figure out template arguments of the make_pair function:

```
m1.insert(make_pair(1,1)); // equivalent o m1.insert(make_pair<int,int>(1,1));
```

or that way:

```
m1[1] = 1;
```

The thing is: when you declare an template variable (`pair` is a type, so `pair<int,int>( 1, 1 )` is a template variable declaration), template parameters must be specified. But, when you call a function (`make_pair` is actually a function), template parameters are optional, compiler will try to determine them and it will only complains if it fails to.

Comment: A better way to do it would be via emplace or m1.insert({1, 1}); and not surely by [] operator as mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/how-do-i-insert-into-a-map .

Comment: Note that `m1[1] = 1` always updates the key `1`, whereas `insert` does not if the key already exists in the map.

Comment: @jpo38 : "_It's redundant, but that't the way it is_" . What kind of declaration of _insert()_ in header of _map_ makes it _that_ way? I have edited my question with example to ask my question in a better way.

Comment: @anurag86 I've edited my answer to show where you've erred.

Comment: @anurag86: `map::insert` is not template itself, it's part of the template map class and reuses the class template parameter `value_type`