# Why cant I insert a struct value in an unordered_map C++

Tags: c++, debugging

I have created a very simple example to show the problem:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    struct Example {
        int num;
        float decimal;
    };

    std::unordered_map<int, Example> map;
    map.insert(1, { 2, 3.4 }); // Error none of the overloads match!
}
```

I should be able to insert into the map of int and struct Example but the compiler says none of the overloads match..?

Comment: Braced initialization list are typeless, and cannot be perfect-forwarded to a constructor via a template, like `std::map::insert`.

Comment: `std::unordered_map::insert` doesn't take two parameters. Or at least, it doesn't take key and value as two separate parameters. `map.insert({1, { 2, 3.4 }});` [works](https://godbolt.org/z/z9fYa4EsY)

Comment: Off the top of my head, `map.emplace(1, Example{ 2, 3.4 });`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't see how this is relevant? It doesn't work because `insert` doesn't accept parameters like these. It would work with `emplace()` call or if the pair was constructed using another pair of braces. I replaced the duplicate target for now, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I reopened the question, because of invalid close reason. See also @John's and Yksisarvinen's comment and existing answer.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Is [What is the preferred/idiomatic way to insert into a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286670/what-is-the-preferred-idiomatic-way-to-insert-into-a-map) an incorrect duplicate target? It answers in greater detail how to correctly insert elements into map and mentions `emplace()` (which answer here fails to do).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I wouldn't consider the question, but at least one of the top answers point into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error message is, that none of the overloads of `std::unordered_map::insert` takes a key and a value parameter.

You should do

```
map.insert({1, { 2, 3.4 }});
```

instead of

```
map.insert(1, { 2, 3.4 });
```

You may refer to the 6th overload of std::unordered_map::insert at
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert

Comment: An explanation, why this is the correct answer would be helpful