# Pulling info from a file into a map and need to overwrite duplicate values?

Tags: c++, dictionary

Hi so I have a homework assignment and have it all done except for the last requirement. We're pulling in data from a txt file and several of the box office values are 0. Instead of returning the first instance of 0, we are to return the last instance of 0. Here's a snippet of code:

```
long long worldBoxOffice = movie.getWorldBoxOffice();
movieMap.insert(pair<long long, Movie>(worldBoxOffice, movie));
```

So after inserting the pair into the map, what is it that I should be doing? Would it be overloading the [] operator? Kinda confused so any help is appreciated. I didn't post more code because I'm not looking for code, just a push in the right direction as to how to go about it. Thanks.

Note: we have to use maps, not allowed to use multi maps, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `insert` [doesn't replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than) existing keys, you should not be using it in the first place. Nothing after such an (ineffective) insert will get your data back.

You can use the `[]` operator: `movieMap[worldBoxOffice] = movie;` or do the insertions in reverse order - read the file backwards.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am misunderstanding but if you just use `operator []` instead to assign to the map when you read in your data you will end up with the last `0` instance that you read in, like this trivial example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<int,int>
    m ;

    m[0] = 1 ;

    std::cout << m[0] << std::endl ;

    m[1] = 2 ;

    m[0] = 3 ;

    std::cout << m[0] << std::endl ;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that's not the case with `insert`.

Comment: @aib I was suggesting to just use `[]` but maybe it does not read clearly, let me adjust