# std::map::insert/operator[] hybrid for inserting mostly-ordered values to STL maps?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I need to merge and edit multiple [Motorolla S-Record (MOT/SREC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_%28file_format%29) files that each consist of memory addresses and the associated contents, and are therefore generally ordered by the memory address (unless someone hand-edits it or something), and then write the result back out (in order) to a single S-Rec file.

To allow easy ordering and processing of the addresses, I decided to use a map with the memory address as an integer key and the full SREC line (including the address) as a string value, e.g. `std::map<int,std::string> mymap;`

Since the files may have overlapping regions, the 'merge' will have to allow subsequent values to overwrite any existing ones. Since `std::insert` will not replace an existing value, my thought was to use `operator[]`, but then two things piqued my interest:

1. `std::insert` also has a form that takes an `iterator position` 'hint' and returns an `iterator`, which seems especially suited for the type of mostly-ordered insert I'll be doing - the data following an insert is *very* likely to follow it in order, so why not give the last position as a hint (i.e. just pass the iterator the last `insert` call returned to the next `insert` call)?
2. From the [SGI STL reference](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html), "`m[k]` is equivalent to `(*((m.insert(value_type(k, data_type()))).first)).second`", which made me wonder if I could combine the hint form and the operator (w/ replacement) form... After all, complexity for both is logarithmic unless a good hint is provided for the insert, in which case it becomes an 'amortized constant'...

Which all comes down to: **Is there an issue with combining insert-with-hint and operator[] by inserting a 'hint' into the operator[] syntax?** e.g. `(*(m.insert(hint, value_type(k, data_type())))).second = value;` (This does still create a value using the default constructor before assigning the new value, which may be avoided somehow, but I'm not too worried about it right now for string values...)

---

**Bonus:** is there a reason why this isn't written as `(m.insert(hint, value_type(k, data_type())))->second`, or in the original example `(*((m.insert(value_type(k, data_type()))).first)).second`? Is there something special about the iterator or something?

---

(For what it's worth, "[In STL maps, is it better to use map::insert than []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than)" deals with the *choice between* `insert` and `operator[]`, and answers there tend to argue for readability in general, which is fine and is good practice *in general*, but this question deals especially with ordered (or mostly-ordered) data that may make some level of optimization worth it.)

Comment: Given the sizes of most S-record files I've seen, and the fact that you're (presumably) doing this mixed with I/O, I'd be fairly surprised if any of this made any real difference -- the I/O time will typically dominate.

Comment: About the combine insert-with-hint and operator[], what do you mean? Create your own operator[] to admit a hint (deriving from map, for example)? Or just using the code you sample to insert the element?

Comment: About the bonus: I don't think are any special reason, since map impose bidirectional iterator requirements, where both codes are equivalent. In C++98 operator[] is defined as in SGI documentation, but not in C++11: "_Effects: If there is no key equivalent to `x` in the map, inserts `value_type(x, T())` into the map._"

Comment: @Gonmator, I was just planning to use the code sample to insert the element, not creating my own operator[]...

Comment: @JerryCoffin, that's pretty much what I expected to hear, but I was still curious whether the construct would be useful at all...

Comment: @johnny: I don't see any issue by using the sample code with the hint. Because is just a hint, in the worst case (STL implementation, or bad hint used) you get the same complexity time.