# Why is map::operator[] slow by design?

Tags: c++, performance, stl, std, libstdc++

### The problem:

Peope complain about this: 
[In STL maps, is it better to use map::insert than []?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than)

When accessing

```
std::map<Key, ExpensiveDefaultConstructorValue> data;
data[key1] // <-- Calls default constructor each time it is called, 
           // even when the element is there
```

The implementation is simple and elegant, but completely inefficient (well, taken from unordered_map).

```
_Tp& operator[](const key_type& __key)
   { return _M_ht.find_or_insert(value_type(__key, _Tp())).second; }
```

### The obvious solution

```
_Tp& operator[](const key_type& __key)
   { return _M_ht.find_or_insert_default(key_type(__key)).second; }
```

Where `find_or_insert_default` would call `_Tp()` only if needed (i.e. the element does not exist)

### Why not?

Is it some other problem that may be caused by this pessimistic approach in building a new element before knowing you need it?

This is standard library, they should go to great lengths to optimize it. Why not use this simple approach?

Comment: Are you sure he spec requires this? Could a conformant implementation be more efficient?

Comment: Well, this is what I ask. Code example is from gcc's libstdc++

Comment: One naive hypothesis might be that whoever wrote that code did not consider the possibility that the default ctor may incur a non-trivial cost.

Comment: What you proposed is done (depending on compiler version). However it doesn't address the problem of `data[non_existing_key] = some_new_value` which requires the creation of the default value so it can be assigned to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There hasn't been such issue with `std::map` at least since [g++ 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01033_source.html#l00443):

```
// stripped comments and requirements
mapped_type&
operator[](const key_type& __k)
{    
    iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);

    if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
        __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
    return (*__i).second;
}
```

The snippet you posted isn't from `std::map`, but from `hash_map`, which was a GCC [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00889_source.html#l00052) to the library:

```
00052 /** @file backward/hash_map
00053  *  This file is a GNU extension to the Standard C++ Library (possibly
00054  *  containing extensions from the HP/SGI STL subset).
00055  */
```

Since it's an extension the maintainers are not really obligated to follow any complexity/performance rules (even though your proposed function would be faster). Note that `hash_map` has been replaced by an implementation for `std::unordered_map`, which doesn't use the constructor if the element exists.