# Obtain iterator upon adding to std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Are there any methods of procuring an iterator, when working with a Standard Library map container, which don't require searching throughout the container?

I have a managing class for a map, and I wish to return the iterator associated to items added to the map. I don't want to rely upon find() if at all possible. If I can avoid searches I figure all the better.

```
std::map<char, bool>::iterator ClassA::Add(char item)
{
  mymap[item] = false;
  return mymap.get_iterator_lastitem();
}
```

Perhaps

```
return mymap.end() - 1;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326062/in-stl-maps-is-it-better-to-use-mapinsert-than

Comment: Most containers have an `insert` method that returns an iterator, `map` is [no exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) (although it returns the iterator as a pair).

Comment: See [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert). Also, as `std::map` is sorted, adding a new item using the index operation (like `mymap[key] = data`) the new item may not be the "last" item in the map.

Comment: First person to post this as an answer gets the points. Thanks regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using C++11, then

```
std::map<char, bool>::iterator ClassA::Add(char item)
{
   std::pair<std::map<char, bool>::iterator, bool> result = mymap.insert(std::make_pair(item, false));
   if(!result.second) {
       // Item already exists, modify that existing item
       result.first->second = false;
   }

   return result.first;
}
```

If you are using C++11 then it is better to use `emplace` + `auto`.

```
std::map<char, bool>::iterator ClassA::Add(char item)
{
   auto result = mymap.emplace(item, false);
   if(!result.second) {
      // Item already exists, modify that existing item
      result.first->second = false;
   }

   return result.first;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d76f719aa3db37e9)

Both `insert` and `emplace` return a pair of an iterator and a boolean, of which the iterator points to the inserted or existing element and the boolean indicates whether an insertion (`true`) took place or if not (`false`) of which the returned iterator points to the already-existing element with the key.