# Initialize a value in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary

I wondered when i put a value to it's key in two ways :

```
map<string, int> m;
 m["a"] = 20;
```

and:

```
m.insert(make_pair("a", 20));
```

what is the difference between them? Thanks.

Comment: There are other duplicates too. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/326062/1870232)