# Why can't std::map::insert take a key and a value rather than an std::pair?

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, stl, containers

std::map has the member function

```
template <class P> pair<iterator,bool> insert (P&& val);
```

which we use e.g. like so:

```
my_map.insert(std::make_pair(k, v));
```

Question is, why isn't there a variant of `insert()` which just takes a key and a value, i.e.

```
pair<iterator,bool> insert (K&& key, V&& value);
```

(with K and V being the template parameters of the map of course) which we would use e.g. like so:

```
my_map.insert(k, v);
```

That seems to me perfectly reasonable to have.

Answer (score 2):

This was added in C++11 with the `emplace` members for all containers, which for `map` has the signature

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

Comment: emplace and insert are two different things - one of them gets values, the other gets constructor arguments. Can you explain how you believe `emplace()` is the same as my suggested variant of `insert()`?

Comment: @einpoklum the Standard Container requirements summarized table 102 of [N4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf) state that `emplace` forwards its arguments to the constructor of a container's `value_type`. For `std::map`, this means that `emplace(k,v)` will insert a `std::pair<const K, V>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a more obvious syntax, you can perform the same insertion using the key and values as separate entities like this:

```
my_map[k] = v;
```

Granted, this is two separate operations. An insert followed by an assignment so it may not be as efficient as a single insert. But then again, maps store store their entries as pairs so a call to an `insert(k, v)` function would probably wind up creating a `pair<k, v>` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but - that's not what I was asking. I know about `operator[]` - and I also know it [has its problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/327289/1593077).